# XSLT Count tabledatas from one row

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I want to count how many td's one tr have.

My XML:

```
<table-opt>
    <tablerow>
        <table_data>test</table_data>
    </tablerow>
    <tablerow>
        <table_data>test2</table_data>
    </tablerow>
    <tablerow>
        <table_data>test3</table_data>
    </tablerow>
</table-opt>
```

And my XSL:

```
 <xsl:template name="table-opt">
    <xsl:variable name="countdata" select="count(.//tablerow/table_data)"></xsl:variable>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fullwidth" width="640px">
            <tr>
                <td width="640px" align="center">
                   <xsl:value-of select="$countdata"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</xsl:template>
```

So now it gives me the answer 3. I do understand why, but I actually want the answer 1 because I have only one `table_data` in each `tablerow`. How could I do this?

I know that if in one `tablerow` are two `table_data` I would have a problem. But forget this option, it will never happen.

Comment: divide them by the number of table rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Just put the $countdata variable in a for-each for each tablerow. I hope I can help other users with a similar problem.